# .NET testing framework advice

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I'm looking to introduce a unit testing framework into the mix at my job.  We're using Visual Studio 2005 (though we may be moving to 2008 within the next six months) and work primarily in C#. If the framework has some kind of IDE integration that would be best, but I'm open to frameworks that don't have integration but are still relatively simple to get set up.  I'm going to get resistance to it one way or another, so if I can make sure what I'm pushing isn't a pain in the neck, that would help my case.

The obvious choice from the research I've done so far points to NUnit, but I'd like to get the impressions of someone who's actually used it before recommending it to my team.

Has anyone out there used [NUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit)? If so, are there any pitfalls or limitations of which I should be aware? Are there other good options out there? If so, if you've used both NUnit at that, I'd greatly appreciate an idea of the strengths and weaknesses of them.

Comment: 2008. Facepalm. You should be using 2010 if your upgrading

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think [NUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) **is** your best bet. With [TestDriven.NET](https://testdriven.net/), you get great integration within Visual Studio. (ReSharper also has a unit test runner if you're using it). NUnit is simple to use and follows an established paradigm. You'll also find plenty of projects, tutorials, and guides using it which always helps.

Your other main choice is probably [MbUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#.NET_programming_languages), which is more and more positioning itself as the [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) framework of choice (in conjunction with [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org)).

Answer (score 18):

Scott Hanselman had a good *podcast* about this, entitled:

> "The Past, Present and Future of .NET Unit Testing Frameworks"

:

[Hanselminutes #112](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=130)

Comment: That is was a money podcast. It highlights all the major unit test frameworks. I personally started using xUnit because of what I heard on this pod cast.

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio 2008 has a built-in test project type that works in a similar way to NUnit, but obviously has much tighter integration with Visual Studio (can run on every build and shows the results in a similar way to the conversion results page when upgrading solution files), but it is obviously not as mature as NUnit as it's pretty new and I'm not sure about how it handles mocking.

But it would be worth looking into when your team moves to Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 8):

The built-in unit testing in Visual Studio 2008 is all right, but its difficult to integrate with [CruiseControl.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl), certainly a lot harder than normal NUnit.

So go with NUnit if you plan to have nice automated tests.

Answer (score 6):

We've been using [xUnit.net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit.net). It seems to combine all the best of NUnit, [MbUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#.NET_programming_languages), and [MSTest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework).

Comment: I majorly regret the wasted time not having tried it before I switched.

Answer (score 5):

When I started unit testing, I started with NUnit as it is simple to set up and use. Currently I am using the built-in test runner that comes with [ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate). That way, I can easily flip between code and test results.

Incidentally, NUnit detects when you have compiled your code, so you do not need to do any refresh in NUnit. ReSharper automatically does a build when you choose to run a specific test.

Answer (score 5):

Try also the [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) tool.

It's Microsoft's own, probably soon to be integrated into [VSTS](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/).
It does support NUnit, [MbUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#.NET_programming_languages) and [xUnit.net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit.net).

I also use a small console application for testing one class or a small library. You could copy paste the code from [here](http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.com/2009/04/example-console-application-in-c-ready.html).

Answer (score 5):

VSTT 2010 (Visual Studio Team System Test) should be a good bet if you are looking for functional test automation. Web services testing, UI testing, [BizTalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BizTalk_Server) testing and data-driven testing support. Please look at [VSTT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ee338734(v=vs.90)).

Answer (score 4):

[MbUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#.NET_programming_languages) is worth a look. It has a set of features comparable to NUnit. It has its own GUI, or can be integrated into Visual Studio if you have [ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate). I would also recommend *Rhino Mocks* if you are doing any sort of [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

Answer (score 3):

I would say [MbUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#.NET_programming_languages) also. I like being able to run a single test many times just by specifying inputs and the result is right above the test function. It is a horrible description of what I mean, so [here is a link that shows you what I mean](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MbUnitUnitTestingOnCrack.aspx).