# Built in unit-testing in VS

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I'm looking for advice on the built-in unit testing feature provided in VS08. Can any body please tell me if they know of any reasons NOT to use this feature over any of the other packages available (I'm vaguely familiar with NUnit)?

I'm planning on applying unit testing to an older project just to learn the ropes of unit testing and some of the newer features in the .NET 3.5 framework. I like the look of the built in feature as from the quick demo I ran it seemed incredibly easy to use and I generally find Microsoft documentation very helpful.

I'd be very grateful if anyone who is familiar with this feature could alert me to any issues I should be aware of or any reasons to avoid this in favour of another package.

Note: I've tried raking through this (excellent) site for details specific to VS's built in unit testing feature. It has been [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709/net-testing-framework-advice) a few times but I couldn't an exact match but please accept my apologies if this has been answered elsewhere.

Thank you, Eric

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92869/nunit-vs-visual-studio-2008s-test-projects-for-unit-testing) can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax can be a little clumsy, but if you're only trying to get to grips with unit testing, then there will be no harm in using the built-in stuff